# Вызов функции посредством кнопки js

Tags: javascript

Ребят, помогите с домашним заданием пожалуйста. Код почему не срабатывает.

```js
function Func() {
  var result = document.getElementById("num");
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtInput")).value;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < x) {
    result.innerHTML = i;
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  </br>
  </br>
  Enter your number: &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" id="txtInput" />
  </br>
  </br>
  <input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Calculate number!" onClick="Func()" />
  <p id="num"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: `var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);`

Comment: Спасибо большое,  Игорь! Сейчас у меня выдает на странице последнюю введеную цифру, а как сделать так, что бы на странице отобразились все цифры в цикле? Например, если вводишь цифру 3 - то на экране: 0,1,2

Comment: `Например, если вводишь цифру 3 - то на экране: 0,1,2` - либо заводишь переменную до цикла, конкатинируешь с ней в цикле и потом результат выводишь в `innerHTML` либо (плохо но) в каждой итерации цикла берешь данные из `innerHTML`, конкатинируешь число и отправляешь обратно в `innerHTML` ........ хотя в данном случае можно просто написать без всяких циклов `result.innerHTML = Array.from(Array(5).keys()).join()` или `result.innerHTML =
 [...Array(5).keys()]`, где 5 - это значение икса

Comment: У меня вроде переменная заявлена до цикла. Получается это сделать с document.write    но так, чтобы результат выводился с inner.HTML на ту же страницу - не получается

Comment: Спасибо Вам) просто смысл в том чтобы отработать цикл while

Comment: `У меня вроде переменная заявлена до цикла` - не та переменная. я про строковую... то есть имеется до цикла переменная `var resultStr = ''`....... вот в цикле нужно с ней конкатинировать то, что в итоге попадет в результирующий html. То есть своего рода аккумулятор. `while (i < x) {
    resultStr += (i++) + ',';
  }` ........ а после цикла уже весь этот собранный контент помещать в нужный html `result.innerHTML = resultStr;`

Comment: Я поняла)))) Спасибо вам умные люди)))

Answer (score 0):

Собрал все, может кому-то поможет

```js
function Func() {
  var result = document.getElementById("num");
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);
  var i = 0;
  var endNums = '';
  while (i < x) {
    if (i == x - 1) {
      endNums += i
    } else {

      endNums += i + ',';
    }
    i++;
  }
  result.innerHTML = endNums;
};
```

```html
<form>
  </br>
  </br>
  Enter your number: &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" id="txtInput" />
  </br>
  </br>
  <input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Calculate number!" onClick="Func()" />
  <p id="num"> </p>
</form>
```